# yacc/bison identify result in action

Tags: bison, yacc, parser-generator

I am using Jflex, byacc, java for parsing statement which looks something like

```
where expr,expr having expr
```

and the grammer looks like

```
%token WHERE HAVING COMMA
%%

stmt : whereclause havingclause

whereclause : WHERE conditionlist { move tmpList to whereClause};
havingclause : HAVING conditionlist { move tmpList to havingClause};

conditionlist : condition | condition COMMA conditionlist;

condition : expr { tmpList.add($1); 
                  /How do I know this is being executed for whereclause or havingclause /};

expr : ....
```

I am not able to differentiate if condition is part of whereclause or havingclause, So I am storing conditions in temporary list and then moving to the right clause.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly, you build the data structures in the rule actions, assigning pointers to them to `$$` and then read them in the higher level rules.  Something like:

```
%token WHERE HAVING COMMA
%union {
    class List *listptr;
    class Expr *exprptr;
}
%type<listptr> whereclasue havingclause conditionlist
%type<exprptr> condition expr
%destructor { delete $$; } <listptr>
%destructor { delete $$; } <exprptr>
%%

stmt : whereclause havingclause { do something with $1 and $2... }

whereclause : WHERE conditionlist { $$ = $2; };
havingclause : HAVING conditionlist { $$ = $2 };

conditionlist : condition { $$ = new List($1); }
              | condition COMMA conditionlist { $$ = $2->prepend($1); };

condition : expr { $$ = $1; }

expr : ....
```

Note the `%destructor` actions are a bison extension, and are needed to avoid memory leaks when there are syntax errors.